# Using predefined command or coordinate with \draw bend right

Tags: tikz-pgf

I ran into this problem when using `draw` with a predefined command.
Any idea how to fix? Here's a minimal (not) working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\Ve}{(1,1)}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (1,0) to[bend right] (1,1) ; %works
        \draw   \Ve to[bend right] (1,0) ; %works
        \draw (1,0) to[bend right] \Ve ;   %doesn't work
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The error produced:

`Latex Error: ./untitled.tex:9 Package tikz Error: (, +, coordinate, pic, or node expected.
Latex Error: ./untitled.tex:9 Package pgf Error: No shape named is known.`

Comment: You could use `coordinate` like this: `\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (VE) at (1,1);
        \draw (1,0) to[bend right] (1,1) ; 
        \draw (VE) to[bend right] (1,0) ; 
        \draw (1,0) to[bend right] (VE) ;   
    \end{tikzpicture}`

Comment: @Bobyandbob that answers my question as far as I'm concerned

Comment: @BjørnKjos-Hanssen Although the `coordinate` way is the cleanest and preferred way, you may be interested in that defining `\Ve` without parenthesis; that is, `\newcommand{\Ve}{1,1}`; and then using `(\Ve)` instead of `\Ve`, also works.

Comment: The first one will work with `\expandafter\draw \Ve` but the second would be more complex and this approach is not to be recommended.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need parentheses. With `\draw` the path, which is specified with for example two points should be drawn. The coordinates of the start and end positions are specified as points in ***round brackets.*** [See: [2.3 Straight Path Construction](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf?lang=de),p.31]

Definition: **point position**

- in cm: `(1,0)` and `(1,1)`

  > The positions are specified within a special coordinate system in which, initially, one unit is `1cm`. [See [2.2.1 Setting up the Environment in LATEX](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf?lang=de) p.29-30]
- in pt: `(1pt,0pt)` and `(1pt,1pt)` -> The positions are specified within a special coordinate system  with unit`pt`.
- in polar coordinates: `(0:1)` and `(45:{sqrt(2)})`-> polar coordinates: `1` respectively `sqrt(2)` (as radius) in direction `0` respectively 
  `45` degree (angle). To calculate `{sqrt(2)}` (to get the correct radius) you need `\usetikzlibrary{calc}`.See [2.15 Specifying Coordinates](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf?lang=de),p37ff.
- with macro: `(\Va)` and `(\Ve)` -> TikZ parser understands coordinates and nodes(and their names) by explicitly looking for `(` character in the input stream. Hence if brackets are hidden inside the macro, the parser first fail to find the bracket and will then expand the macro which will be too late. Instead define your own commands with `\newcommand{\Va}{1,0}` and `\newcommand{\Ve}{1,1}` ( hint from @JLDiaz comment)

But i prefer and recommend:

- with coordinates: `(A)` and `(B)` -> Defining two coordinates (name: **A**, **B**) using the `\coordinate` command. For example `\coordinate (A) at (1,0);` and `\coordinate (B) at (1,1);`

Solution:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usetikzlibrary{calc}
%\newcommand{\Ve}{1,1}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (VE) at (1,1);
   %\coordinate (VE) at (45:{sqrt(2)});
        \draw (1,0) to[bend right] (1,1);
        \draw   (VE) to[bend right] (1,0);
        \draw (1,0) to[bend right] (VE) ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
%    \begin{tikzpicture}
%        \draw (1,0) to[bend right] (1,1);
%        \draw (\Ve) to[bend right] (1,0);
%        \draw (1,0) to[bend right] (\Ve) ;
%    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```